# How do you call the act of missing class/lectures/lessons and cheat on a test?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

Imagine a student that is not taking school seriously and misses or skips classes on purpose and cheat on tests.

In Portuguese, missing/skipping a class/lesson/lecture is called 'matar aula' ("to kill a class") and to cheat on a test is called "colar na prova" ("to glue on a test").

How do you call those in English?

Comment: We say it exactly as you wrote - ***missing / skipping*** classes, and ***cheating*** in tests.

Comment: thanks. please make it an answer.

Comment: But I don't really see a *question* here! Unless you're asking for "idiomatic" alternatives to the natural words you and I have just used. For example, some (mainly British) kids might still talk about [***bunking off***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bunk%20off#:~:text=1%20%3A%20to%20not%20go%20to,from%20school%2C%20work%2C%20etc.) school in general, some specific subject, or a single lesson. But that's pretty old slang, and I don't know what the kids today would say instead. And ***playing truant*** sounded positively Victorian to me even way back when ***I*** was a schoolboy!

Comment: (btw - cheating in academic tests sounds like a pretty dumb life strategy to me. Who wants to end up in a job they're actually not sufficiently clever / educated to do properly?)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - believe me, some people will do anything.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica they do it in the same way: by cheating, and feeding off others' ability. Such people often get rapid promotion out of harm's way, and can do very well. Or they gain employment through nepotism.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Way back when I was a first-year student at uni, there was one girl who was repeating her first year because she'd *failed* first time around. Presumably she didn't cheat (or didn't cheat well enough!). She was a perfectly pleasant girl, but obviously not bright enough to get through a degree course. Perhaps she only managed to be there at all because she cheated in her school exams. But I certainly remember feeling sorry for her - she was a real "fish out of water", who eventually ended up leaving before reaching the end of her second attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple, natural way to express this is "skipping" or "missing classes" and "cheating" in exams.  You don't need anything else.

Skipping classes is formally "truancy", and casually there are lots of slang phrases "bunking off", "playing hooky" and "skiving" are older ones.  Kids probably invent new slang terms for this sort of thing everyday.

I can't think of another way of saying "cheating". I suppose "dishonest practices in examinations".  I suppose by far the most common type of cheating is "copying" from your neighbour.