# Do we say "a student quits class/school" when he is lazy to go to class/school but not quit class/school permanently?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

When we say "**he quit school**" it means he left school permanently and never come back.

However, some students are lazy to go to class/school but that doesn't mean they "**quit class/school permanently**". They will go back to class/school the next day.

Do we say "**the boy quit class today because he was lazy but he will be back tomorrow**"?

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/265017/how-do-you-call-the-act-of-missing-class-lectures-lessons-and-cheat-on-a-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put:

> he skipped class/school

This reveals how he did not come for class and **will come back**, therefore "skip".

Comment: As the answer to the duplicate question states, there are many slang terms for playing truant from school.